# Hover DropDown Menu Malfunction

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with creating a hoverable dropdown menu. If I take away the second part of my statement in my hover ( `.dropMenu` ) the hover function works on the header button, so I know it's not an issue there. I'm extremely stuck, and cannot see any issues. Here is my code:

```css
.dropMenu {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -18px;
  
}

.drop:hover .dropMenu{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="HTMLRef1.html">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class ="drop">Hover Dropdown</a>
  <a href="#" >Contact</a>
</nav>
<div class="dropMenu">
  <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
  <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
  <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
</div>
```

The header button that says "DropDown Content" has a class of `drop` . The actual dropdown menu has a class of `dropMenu`

Comment: I have also tried to switch the hover over to the entire navbar to see if it's an issue with the sizing of the dropdown button. Doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think @plaisk answer is probably right. It might look ugly, but does it suddenly work if you put the "dropMenu" div inside of the "drop" class?

Answer (score 2):

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502693/12888797

Your current code will only work if your dropdown menu is inside the element with the drop class

Comment: so I changed my hover command over to: 

` #nav .drop:hover ~ #nav #droptest{
  background-color: orange;
}
`
and my index file to :
`<nav id="nav">
        <a href="HTMLRef1.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class ="drop">Hover Dropdown</a>
        <a href="#" id="droptest"> test1 </a>
        <a href="#" >Contact</a>
    </nav>`

And it's still not working. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work by making the div with the "dropMenu" class a sibling of the element with the "drop" class, and adding ~ in the hover part of the css (use that to indicate that it's a sibling of the element you're hovering over that should be affected).

```css
.dropMenu {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -18px;
  
}

.drop:hover ~ .dropMenu{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="HTMLRef1.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class ="drop">Hover Dropdown</a>
    <a href="#" >Contact</a>
    <div class="dropMenu">
        <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
        <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
        <a href= "#">MenuItem1 </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```